# Flash - Zoom out on image

Tags: flash, zooming, flash-cs5

I'm a complete newb when it comes to Flash. But I heard what I want is possible in Flash;

I'm looking to zoom in on an image:
Example: Picture of a church. Zoom in as far as possible on the church tower.

Then it needs to slowly zoom out, so you have time to guess which church it could be.
Example: Slowly zooms out, revealing more and more of the picture.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you have done for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a complete newb as you say, then diving right into actionscript 3 and tweening libraries probably isn't the best solution. Heres an article + a video tutorial on how you basically accomplish this effect, just backwards. The person is starting zoomed out and zooming in but by learning the principles you should be able to easily modify the effect to suit your needs.

http://www.hypergurl.com/blog/flash/zoom-rescale.html

Also if you're interested in getting deeper into flash, I would then advise as Andreas has, that you look into coding (learn actionscript 3, not actionscript 2), using tweening libraries, classes etc. The following website is an excellent free resource of video tutorials, sample projects and more to learn a wide range of things in flash from basic to advanced applications.

http://gotoandlearn.com/index.php

All the best.

Answer (score 3):

First you will need a quite high resolution image for it not to be too pixelated when zoomed in. Also make sure to set the smoothing property of the bitmap to true (this can be done by code or in the library.

To zoom it out either go by a timeline animtation or use a tweening library, preferably Greensock tweening library: http://www.greensock.com/

You need to modify the scaleX and scaleY parameters.